# Guzzle not using base uri when a dynamic endpoint is selected (Works locally but not on K8S)

Tags: php, docker, lumen, guzzle6

I am building an API Gateway and a bunch of microservices to run my company. I have elected to use PHP as it is what I have the most experience with.

Local Setup: Opensuse Tumbleweed, PHPStorm, php7.3, SQLite, docker
Remote Setup: GKE, PHP7.3 Percona Xtra DB and Docker

I am using Laravels Lumen Framework 5.8.

My gateway communicates with the microservices via Guzzle6 Http Client and locally works great. When it is pushed to the cluster using Gitlab to run a ci/cd pipeline to compile it as a docker image and deploy it to Kubernetes on Google Cloud.

I have tried switching between "" and '',
I have rewritten the entire code,
I have looked over the Guzzle Documentation,
I have read many stack overflow questions of similar behaviour in docker

routes

```
    $router->get('/customers','CustomerController@getAll');
    $router->post('/customers','CustomerController@createCustomer');
    $router->get('/customers/{customer}','CustomerController@getCustomer');
    $router->put('/customers/{customer}','CustomerController@updateCustomer');
    $router->patch('/customers/{customer}','CustomerController@updateCustomer');
    $router->delete('/customers/{customer}','CustomerController@deleteCustomer');
```

controller

```
public function updateCustomer(Request $request, $customer)
    {
        return $this->successResponse($this->customerService->updateCustomer($request->all(), $customer));
    }

    public function deleteCustomer($customer)
    {
        return $this->successResponse($this->customerService->deleteCustomer($customer));
    }
```

service

```
public function createCustomer($data)
    {
        return $this->performRequest('POST','', $data);
    }

    public function getCustomer($customer)
    {
        return $this->performRequest('GET', "/{$customer}");
    }

    public function updateCustomer($data, $customer)
    {
        return $this->performRequest('PUT', "{$customer}", $data);
    }

    public function deleteCustomer($customer)
    {
        return $this->performRequest('DELETE', "{$customer}");
    }
```

performRequest

```
public function performRequest($method, $requestUrl, $formParams = [], $headers = [])
    {
        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => $this->baseUri,
        ]);
        $response = $client->request($method, $requestUrl, ['form_params' => $formParams, 'headers' => $headers]);
        return $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }
```

Endpoints Locally:
- GET /contacts WORKS!
- POST /contacts WORKS!
- GET /contacts/(contacts UUID identifier) WORKS!
- PUT/PATCH /contacts/(contacts UUID identifier) WORKS!
- DELETE /contacts/(contacts UUID identifier) WORKS!

Endpoints Production:
- GET /contacts WORKS!
- POST /contacts WORKS!
- GET /contacts/(contacts UUID identifier) FAILS!
- PUT/PATCH /contacts/(contacts UUID identifier) FAILS!
- DELETE /contacts/(contacts UUID identifier) FAILS!

Sentry Bug Tracker shows GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
cURL error 3:  (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

when looking at the URL on sentry the base URI is getting ignored on the endpoints that are failing but this doesn't happen on my local machine.

Comment: Could you further describe what fails? Does it give a 404? Are you sure the contacts actually exist in the database?

Comment: Hi @MaartenDev It gives a 500 Internal Server Error which sends a guzzle error code of 3 which is malformed url to sentry bug tracker .

Comment: it should be sending the request to customer-microservice.customer-microservice.cluster.local/customers/(uuid) instead its only going to /(uuid)

Comment: The uuid is obtained by doing a normal GET request and copy and pasting the ID im testing with Postman

Comment: A a 500 error indicated that something went wrong in that microservice. Is there any logging? Are you sure that logging is configured correctly?

Comment: Checked the logs the guzzle is erroring before the request is sent with a malformed url error. The problem is the base uri seems to be getting ignored when a variable in this case uuid based id is appended to grab that specific record from the database

Comment: Are you sure the baseUri is set? could you print the request uri before sending the guzzle request?

Comment: Base URI is definitely set and working or the normal calls without a unique identifier would also fail.

Comment: For lumen to append the ID number that was requested i followed https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters This bit works

Comment: It then calls this function: public function getCustomer($customer)
    {
        return $this->successResponse($this->customerService->getCustomer($customer));
    }

Comment: I don't have enough rep to move to chat. that last function successfully calls public function getCustomer($customer)
    {
        return $this->performRequest('GET', "/{$customer}");
    }

Comment: That should send a guzzle request to baseuri/(customer uuid number) but instead its only sending to /(customer uuid number)

Comment: Could you log `$requestUrl ` and `$this->baseUri` for every call to `performRequest`. Then check if all values are filled correctly?

Comment: at Client->request('GET', '/d9a7babe-99f2-46a1-bee8-0334926e93a4', array('form_params' => array(), 'headers' => array(), 'synchronous' => true))
in ConsumeMicroServices.php line 14 (Error Malformed Request)

Comment: at Client->request('GET', 'http://customer-microservice.customer-microservice.svc.cluster.local/customers', array('form_params' => array(), 'headers' => array(), 'synchronous' => true))
in ConsumeMicroServices.php line 14 (Works)

Comment: Seems to be " needed when using an id submitted with the request is overriding the baseUri

Comment: Shouldn't the base uri contain the protocol? `http:// customer-microservice.customer-microservice.svc.cluster.local`?

Comment: Now i feel daft that seems to have worked please set it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: Ah no worries, these mistakes are really hard to spot because it looks valid. Added the answer as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url doesn't contain the protocol(`http`) adding this will fix the malformed url error.

Final url:
`http://customer-microservice.customer-microservice.svc.cluster.local`